# Calculate rolling correlation with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of 10 stocks differentiated by PERMNO. I would like to group those stocks by PERMNO and calculate the rolling correlation between the stock return (RET) for each PERMNO with the market return (vwretd). The code I am trying is below.

```
CRSP['rollingcorr'] = CRSP.groupby('PERMNO').rolling_corr(CRSP['RET'],CRSP['vwretd'],10)
```

The error I am getting is below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-c18e1ce01302> in <module>()
      1 #CRSP['rollingcorr'] = CRSP.rolling_corr(CRSP['vwretd'],CRSP['RET'],120)
----> 2 CRSP['rollingmean'] = CRSP.groupby('PERMNO').rolling_corr(CRSP['vwretd'],10)
      3 CRSP.head(20)

C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in __getattr__(self, attr)
    296 
    297         raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" %
--> 298                              (type(self).__name__, attr))
    299 
    300     def __getitem__(self, key):

AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'rolling_corr'
```

please help!

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a small smaple (maybe 5-10 rows) of `CRSP`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pandas.rolling_corr`, not `DataFrame.rolling_corr`. Besides, `groupby` returns a generator. See below code.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("color.csv")
df_gen = df.copy().groupby("Color")

for key, value in df_gen:
    print "key: {}".format(key)
    print value.rolling_corr(value["Value1"],value["Value2"], 3)
```

Output:

```
key: Blue
1          NaN
3          NaN
6     0.931673
8     0.865066
10    0.089304
12   -0.998656
15   -0.971373
17   -0.667316
dtype: float64
key: Red
0          NaN
2          NaN
5    -0.911357
9    -0.152221
11   -0.971153
14    0.438697
18   -0.550727
dtype: float64
key: Yellow
4          NaN
7          NaN
13   -0.040330
16    0.879371
dtype: float64
```

You can change the loop part to the following to view the original dataframe post-grouping with a new column as well.

```
for key, value in df_gen:
    value["ROLL_CORR"] = pd.rolling_corr(value["Value1"],value["Value2"], 3)
    print value
```

Output:

```
   Color    Value1    Value2  ROLL_CORR
1   Blue  0.951227  0.514999        NaN
3   Blue  0.649112  0.513052        NaN
6   Blue  0.148165  0.342205   0.931673
8   Blue  0.626883  0.421530   0.865066
10  Blue  0.286738  0.583811   0.089304
12  Blue  0.966779  0.227340  -0.998656
15  Blue  0.065493  0.887640  -0.971373
17  Blue  0.757932  0.900103  -0.667316
key: Red
   Color    Value1    Value2  ROLL_CORR
0    Red  0.201435  0.981871        NaN
2    Red  0.522955  0.357239        NaN
5    Red  0.806326  0.310039  -0.911357
9    Red  0.656126  0.678047  -0.152221
11   Red  0.435898  0.908388  -0.971153
14   Red  0.116419  0.555821   0.438697
18   Red  0.793102  0.168033  -0.550727
key: Yellow
     Color    Value1    Value2  ROLL_CORR
4   Yellow  0.099474  0.143293        NaN
7   Yellow  0.073128  0.749297        NaN
13  Yellow  0.006777  0.318383  -0.040330
16  Yellow  0.345647  0.993382   0.879371
```

If you want to join them all together after processing (this might be confusing to others, by the way), just use `concat` after processing groups.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("color.csv")
df_gen = df.copy().groupby("Color")

dfs = [] # Container for dataframes.

for key, value in df_gen:
    value["ROLL_CORR"] = pd.rolling_corr(value["Value1"],value["Value2"], 3)
    print value
    dfs.append(value)

df_final = pd.concat(dfs)
print df_final
```

Output:

```
     Color    Value1    Value2  ROLL_CORR
1     Blue  0.951227  0.514999        NaN
3     Blue  0.649112  0.513052        NaN
6     Blue  0.148165  0.342205   0.931673
8     Blue  0.626883  0.421530   0.865066
10    Blue  0.286738  0.583811   0.089304
12    Blue  0.966779  0.227340  -0.998656
15    Blue  0.065493  0.887640  -0.971373
17    Blue  0.757932  0.900103  -0.667316
0      Red  0.201435  0.981871        NaN
2      Red  0.522955  0.357239        NaN
5      Red  0.806326  0.310039  -0.911357
9      Red  0.656126  0.678047  -0.152221
11     Red  0.435898  0.908388  -0.971153
14     Red  0.116419  0.555821   0.438697
18     Red  0.793102  0.168033  -0.550727
4   Yellow  0.099474  0.143293        NaN
7   Yellow  0.073128  0.749297        NaN
13  Yellow  0.006777  0.318383  -0.040330
16  Yellow  0.345647  0.993382   0.879371
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

Running `rolling.corr()` on Python 3.5 generates a warning the function is deprecated and may stop working in future. Using `Series.rolling(window=<period>).corr(other=series)` instead is recommended.
E.g.

```
data['scrip1DailyReturn'].rolling(window=90).corr(other=data['scrip2DailyReturn'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an efficient solution. Fairly simple.

```
def roll_corr_groupby(x,i):
    x['Z'] = rolling_corr(x['col 1'], x['col 2'],i) 
    return x

x.groupby(['key']).apply(roll_corr_groupby)
x.head()
```