# Compute rolling window pairwise correlations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cross-correlation

I'm new to python and am trying to compute rolling cross-correlations among the returns of different stocks. My data frame is huge, and it contains many NaNs. Therefore, rolling_corr() doesn't seem to work very well.

Here is a slice of my data frame
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZBd6.png)

I created a function that generates the correlation matrix and unpivot it back to a data frame in the following way:

```
def corr_func(df,n=None):
    cmat = df.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=n)
    mask = np.ones(cmat.shape,dtype='bool')
    mask[np.triu_indices(len(cmat))] = False
    dfnew = cmat[cmat.notnull()&mask]    
    dfnew = dfnew.stack()
    dfnew = dfnew.reset_index(level=1)
    dfnew.columns = ['PERMNO2','Value']
    dfnew.reset_index(inplace=True)
    dfnew=dfnew.rename(columns = {'PERMNO':'PERMNO1'})
    # Associate with the window (first date and last date)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.sort_values('date',inplace=True)
    dfnew['date_first'] = df['date'].iloc[0]
    dfnew['date_last'] = df['date'].iloc[-1]
    return(dfnew)
```

The resulted data frame aggregates unique pairwise correlations of the stock returns in my sample. Here is a slice of the resulted data frame:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTnbZ.png)

I tried to implement rolling cross-correlations with rolling_apply and this function (corr_func), but did not have any success. 
Is there an elegant way to aggregate rolling cross-correlations in a data frame with rolling_apply or some other methods?

Comment: Good solutions shown [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27069003/2662901).